# Remove punctation from every value in Python dictionary

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary, punctuation

I have a long dictionary which looks like this:

```
name = 'Barack.'
name_last = 'Obama!'
street_name = "President Streeet?"

list_of_slot_names = {'name':name, 'name_last':name_last, 'street_name':street_name}
```

I want to remove the punctation for every slot (name, name_last,...).

I could do it this way:

```
name = name.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
name_last = name_last.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
street_name = street_name.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

Do you know a shorter (more compact) way to write this?

Result:

```
>>> print(name, name_last, street_name)
>>> Barack Obama President Streeet
```

Comment: `list_of_slot_names` is a confusing name for a dict, consider `dict_of_slot_names`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = 'Barack.'
name_last = 'Obama!'
empty_slot = None
street_name = "President Streeet?"

print([str_.strip('.?!') for str_ in (name, name_last, empty_slot, street_name) if str_ is not None])
```

```
-> Barack Obama President Streeet
```

Unless you also want to remove them from the middle. Then do this

```
import re

name = 'Barack.'
name_last = 'Obama!'
empty_slot = None
street_name = "President Streeet?"

print([re.sub('[.?!]+',"",str_) for str_ in (name, name_last, empty_slot, street_name) if str_ is not None])
```

Comment: How can I handle emtpy slots like ``house_number = None``?

Comment: @PParker you mean like so?

Comment: Just realize that I have a slot like ``birthday = '12.12.1974'`` which changes to ``12121974``.
Is is possible to only remove the punctation when it is at the end of the string?

Comment: @PParker yes that's the first part of my answer. Well technically the first part removes it left and right. if you only want to remove it at the right use `rstrip` instead of `strip`

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop / dictionary comprehension

```
{k: v.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for k, v in list_of_slot_names.items()}
```

You can either assign this back to `list_of_slot_names` if you want to overwrite existing values or assign to a new variable

You can also then print via

```
print(*list_of_slot_names.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re, string

s = 'hell:o? wor!d.'

clean = re.sub(rf"[{string.punctuation}]", "", s)

print(clean)
```

output

```
hello world
```